# Crash while training Caffe for object detection

Tags: caffe, object-detection, training-data, nvidia-digits

Training using *DetectNET* model provided by [Kitti](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples/object-detection#dataset-creation) on Tesla-P40(22.4 GB) GPU.

```
F0412 12:27:08.371733 26664 detectnet_transform_layer.cpp:212] Check failed: bboxLen == sizeof(BboxLabel) / sizeof(Dtype) (237 vs. 16) 
    *** Check failure stack trace: ***
        @     0x7fc9f8d9884d  google::LogMessage::Fail()
        @     0x7fc9f8d9a61c  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
        @     0x7fc9f8d9843c  google::LogMessage::Flush()
        @     0x7fc9f8d9af2e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
        @     0x7fc9f9a0758f  caffe::DetectNetTransformationLayer<>::blobToLabels()
        @     0x7fc9f9b3e393  caffe::DetectNetTransformationLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
        @     0x7fc9f9aced98  caffe::Net<>::ForwardFromTo()
        @     0x7fc9f9acf117  caffe::Net<>::Forward()
        @     0x7fc9f9ac27ca  caffe::Solver<>::Test()
        @     0x7fc9f9ac304e  caffe::Solver<>::TestAll()
        @     0x7fc9f9ac561d  caffe::Solver<>::Step()
        @     0x7fc9f9ac5fde  caffe::Solver<>::Solve()
        @           0x40b59b  train()
        @           0x408c0c  main
        @     0x7fc9e7dd4b35  __libc_start_main
        @           0x4094eb  (unknown)
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples/object-detection#dataset-creation) to create dataset in lmdb. what does `bboxLen == sizeof(BboxLabel)` means?

Comment: How far were you into the training?  Iteration number?

Comment: it crashed as soon as it started.

Comment: Please give the full context, then -- such as 10 lines of log file *before* the crash.  I don't recognize this error, but it might help someone else.